# Can I save the search link in my profile?

Tags: feature-request, search

Is there anyway to save the search link for future use? As an example I did a search and got a link with [very good questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nokogiri+ruby+search). Now I am looking for anyway to save this search in my profile. Is this feature available here? I know that I can bookmark each questions, but that's not good always when I found say 50 good answers in a search like above.

Comment: You can always bookmark the search URL, but I suppose you want to preserve the results even if some of them stop matching your search criteria in the future?

Comment: Not a good idea, but if you *really* want to save some very important searches in your profile, you can save it on *about* of your profile.

Answer (score 3):

Just bookmark on the search page, or save the URL:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Humm, you are talking about to save this on the browser itself. But that will be a local save,but I am looking for the global save in the `SO` profile itself. So that I can see those questions wherever I want. :)

Comment: @iAmRubuuu: You can always edit it into your "about me". Add a "my favorite searches" area.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarking is the generic solution to this, as Manishearth mentions.

> Humm, you are talking about to save this on the browser itself. But that will be a local save,but I am looking for the global save in the `SO` profile itself. So that I can see those questions wherever I want.

You could use a browser (or extension) that syncs bookmarks across multiple computers.  This would let you access these 'saved search' bookmarks no matter where you are.

Alternatively, use something like [Delicious](https://delicious.com/) to save your search links.  You can then access your searches on their site from any of your internet-connected devices.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Google Bookmark](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/) to save these searches,rather than saving it in local machine browser. Which will allow me to access these if required globally.

Comment: Better than local bookmark. :)